# How to insert a for loop?

Tags: python

Hi i currently have the following function defined. i need to divide each element in the respective test cases by each dividend. In other words, i need each element in test_case1 to be divided by dividend1, test_case2 to be divided by dividend2, so on and so forth.

Any idea on how i can use the function calculate_quotient_and_remainder(y, d) to do that, using another for loop to run the test cases as well?

```
def calculate_quotient_and_remainder(y, d):
    quotient = []
    remainder = []
    for i in y: 
        quotient.append(i//d)
        remainder.append(i%d)
    print('Quotient: {}'.format(quotient))
    print('Remainder: {}'.format(remainder))

test_case1 = [20,7,88,66,18]
test_case2 = [73,57,67,61,83]
test_case3 = [14,42,45,35,33]
test_case4 = [77,31,44,12,11]
test_case5 = [22,80,80,16,84]

dividend_1 = [9] 
dividend_2 = [9] 
dividend_3 = [4]
dividend_4 = [8] 
dividend_5 = [4]
```

Comment: define your test_cases in a for loop, then iterate through each one calling the function

Answer (score 1):

```py
test_cases = [test_case1, test_case2, test_case3, test_case4, test_case5]
dividends = [dividend_1, dividend_2, dividend_3, dividend_4, dividend_5]

for test in test_cases:
    for dividend in dividends:
        calculate_quotient_and_remainder(test, dividend[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use integer division coupled with regular division. I would also recommend using more descriptive variable names. Here is some quick code I wrote to demonstrate.

```
def calc_quote(divisor, array):
    quot = []
    rem = []
    for number in array:
            quotient = number / divisor
            remainder = number // divisor
            quot.append(quotient)
            rem.append(remainder)
    print(quot)
    print(rem)
```